# How to dial Mobile Broadband Connection at particular time (Schedule Dial)?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, mobile-broadband

I use D-Link DWP-156 Wireless 3G Modem with Vodafone India as ISP.

The mobile broadband connection works perfectly with Network manager (No Problem with connecting or Dialing).

Now I want to dial this connection at particular time at 12am or 0000 hour (as the data charges are low during that period).

How can dial/schedule it at that particular time? If that's not possible... Is there any way to dial it after specific time e.g after 3600 seconds like we use it for shutdown command?

Please recommend any software with GUI or Commands using Terminal.
It is 3G modem (14.4mbps) and I dont want restriction over speed while auto-dialing method.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a Cron job to to dial Mobile Broadband Connection at particular time.

- Open terminal and type

  ```
  crontab -e
  ```

  It will open a cron configuration file.
- Now add following at the end of this file.

  ```
  00 00 * * * nmcli con up id '<BROADBAND CONNECTION NAME HERE>'
  ```

It will connect your  modem  at every 00 hour i.e 12 AM.